# SerialPort.Write(String) issue: Having a synchronised call with UI-Thread

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, ui-thread, begininvoke, timeoutexception

I have searched and find out that SerialPort Class Events have a synchronise call with the UI-Thread, therefore; I have used Delegate with DataReceived Event to BeginInvoke on UI-Thread, below is my code for DataReceived Event,

```
Delegate Sub DataRXPointer(ByVal Buffer As String)

'########### Data Receive Handler ###########
Private Sub COMPort_DataReceivedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles COMPort.DataReceived
    Me.BeginInvoke(New DataRXPointer(AddressOf handleDataRX), COMPort.ReadExisting)
End Sub
```

But there is a problem in the SerialPort.Write(String) method because when I disconnect the port with the application (meaning I switch the router off),  the UI-thread hangs up. For an alternative solution I have assigned WriteTimeout value to 5000 (5-sec) and catching a TimeoutException in try and catch block. Still UI-thread hang for about 25-30 sec then an exception occurs and I dispose and close the port.

```
    WriteTimeout = 5000     '// 5-sec
    ReadTimeout = 5000     '// 5-sec

    Try
        If COMPort.IsOpen Then
            COMPort.Write(dataToSend)
        End If

    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        If COMPort IsNot Nothing Then
            COMPort.Dispose()
            COMPort.Close()
        End If

        Me.Close()

    End Try
```

Because it is hanging up to about 25-30 sec, I presume that this method also have a synchronous call with UI-Thread. Is there any solution to do not sych the serialPort with the UI-Thread means how can I use this serialPort class to work completely on a different thread ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that this hanging for 30-35 seconds is because of the real-port driver. The driver itself taking 30-35 seconds to disconnect from the router. After the driver changes its status to "Reconnecting..." the application releases it job as per normal.